# PhpStorm and Intellij: Joomla Template and Module Development

Tags: joomla, intellij-idea, phpstorm, joomla-module

I am developing **Joomla 2.5** templates and modules with Intellij 13 (which should contain all features of PhpStorm as well). If I just create a new project and set the `content root` to `/var/www/joomla` then I have the complete Joomla directory in Intellij project and autocomplete works with out any problem.

How ever I would prefer to have only the template or module that I am currently working on in my project and link the joomla installation as an external library. Is that possible?

I have currently set up the file system like this. Joomla is under: `/var/www/joomla` and my template is stored under `~/Documents/Code/my-template` with a symlink in `/var/www/joomla/templates`:

```
my-template -> /home/user/Documents/Code/my-template
```

This way I can have multiple Intellij projects in different windows, each with a different module or template. I have already tried different things but the auto-complete simply wont work.

Is there maybe a best practice article that explains how to setup the project structure in Intellij such that the Joomla libraries are correctly imported?

Answer (score 2):

Try configuring the PHP Include Paths

http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/configuring-include-paths.html